# Need some help and explanation with this JavaScript line

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where are the conditionals (if any) and executable parts in:

```
(o = k + 1 < a.length && a.charAt(k + 1) == o) && k++;
```

From jQuery date picker.

Comment: can you share some of the code like what is o,k and a?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take this step by step.

First, let's add in all the remaining parentheses, using the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) rules of JavaScript:

```
( o = (((k + 1) < a.length) && (a.charAt(k + 1) == o)) ) && k++;
```

So it says

1. Compute the value `(k+1) < a.length`.  It will be either `true` or `false`.
2. If this is `false` assign `false` to `o`, otherwise assign the value `(a.charAt(k + 1) == o)` to `o`.
3. If you assigned `false` to `o` you are done.
4. Otherwise increment `k`.

Answer (score 2):

This code is changing the meaning of the content of the variable `o`.

On entry that variable contains a character and on exit it will be either `true` or `false` depending if the character at position `k+1` of the string `a` is exactly that character. In case `k+1` happens to fall outside the string then then `o` will be set to false.

As a side effect in case the character matches this expression also increments `k`.

That code seems to me a case of bad optimization... also I don't uderstand why the need of handling the special case of `k+1` falling outside the string (unless the `o` variable can possibly contain the empty string on input...)

Comment: +1  I noticed that change from character to boolean also.  I wonder if that is the real code. :)

Comment: Seriously cryptic code. I think it is designed to prevent reverse engineering ;)

Comment: May be it is intentional... I've seen programmers that like to try to "save" on local variables for no real reason (normally this only give you back worse compiled code because it confuses the compiler about lifetime).